# Compatibility of the processor with the motherboard

Tags: motherboard, processor

I have a motherboard Hi-Fi a70u3p (http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/ru/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=773) and I need to buy an intel core i5 6600 or equivalent processor. Does this motherboard support this processor model? If not, then advise similar processor that this motherboard supports.

Comment: "Supported Socket FM2+/FM2 processors AMD A-series/ E2-series processor" - No, this board doesn't support Intel CPUs at all. You need an AMD.

Answer (score 1):

Your mainboard takes AMD Socket FM2/FM2+ CPUs.  That's a fairly old socket, designed for AMD's APU-series processors, so modern high-power CPUs aren't available for it.

The closest you're going to get to the performance of an i5-6600 is the [A10-7890K](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113402), currently available from Newegg for $150.  It benchmarks about 10% slower than the i5-6600 for single-threaded work, and about 30% slower for multi-threaded.  This may or may not be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy mentioned in the comments, this is an old AMD board. The FM2 socket is a few generations old at this point. You're going to have to find a used CPU that is compatible with the board, as AMD no longer manufactures any CPU that is compatible with it.

You can find a list of supported CPU models by looking for your motherboard's user manual online, or viewing a compiled list on the wikipedia article regarding the FM2 socket, or by using a site such as www.pcpartpicker.com. Good places to look for old hardware are Ebay and a community on Reddit called "r/hardwareswap" (without quotes).